# How to use FileUtils IO correctly?

Tags: java, selenium

I tried to use method (credits to [Shenyuan Lu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/921262/how-to-download-and-save-a-file-from-internet-using-java/7156178#7156178) ):

`org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyURLToFile(URL, File)`

Precisely:

`org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyURLToFile(driver.getCurrentUrl(), "C:\\Users\\myDocs\\myfolder\myFile.pdf");`

However,`Eclipse` is underlining the `copyURLToFile` and suggesting to use `copyFile`. When I switch to `copyFile`, it suggests to use `copyURLToFile` again???

Comment: haha, you are on a question spree..

Comment: thank you for constant help :) +100

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the [FileUtils#copyURLToFile() API](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#copyURLToFile%28java.net.URL,%20java.io.File%29)...

The first parameter needs to be a `URL` object, and the second parameter needs to be a `File` Object. You are passing Strings as both args. Try...

```
org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyURLToFile(new URL(driver.getCurrentUrl()), new File("C:\\Users\\myDocs\\myfolder\\myFile.pdf"));
```

Also, since this method throws an exception, you either need to make your method throw an exception, or surround the statement in a try {} catch{} block.

e.g.

```
try {
    org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyURLToFile(new URL(driver.getCurrentUrl()), new File("C:\\Users\\myDocs\\myfolder\\myFile.pdf"));
} catch (Exception x) { x.printStackTrace(); }
```

Comment: Thank You. I tried this. However, Eclipse is still underlining the `copyURLToFile`

Comment: what does it say in particular?

Comment: edited again... copy and paste that last part. should be golden.

Comment: although it saves .pdf, the file is damaged. Do you know it happenes?

Comment: i havn't the foggiest.. might need to open a new question.