# Why the files downloaded from browser is corrupted?

Tags: java, server, network-programming, client

I started creating a HTTP server application in java. when i tried to download a file from browser, the file size is incresed by 1 byte. and the file is not openning.

content-length : 12345
original size: 12345
downloaded size : 12346

```
                        ResHead resHead = new ResHead(StatusCode.OK);

                        String responseHeader = resHead
                                                .addContentTypeFromFile(file.getName())
                                                .addContentLength(file.length())
                                                .getResponseHeader();

                        os.write(responseHeader.getBytes());


                        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);

                        BufferedInputStream in = 
                            new BufferedInputStream(fileInputStream);

                            OutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(os); // for writing

                        System.out.println(file.length());
                        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024 * 50];
                        int len = 0;
                        while ((len = in.read(buffer)) >= 0) {
                                out.write(buffer, 0, len);
                        }
                        fileInputStream.close();
                        os.flush();
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why a downloaded file can get corrupted?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19309822/why-a-downloaded-file-can-get-corrupted)

Comment: Possible newline translation (from `"\n"` to `"\r\n"`)? Use some kind of comparison tool to find out where the difference is between the files, and what that single extra byte is (and check its surrounding bytes).

Comment: @Royce that is not a duplicate.

Comment: You are supposed to flush `out`, not `os`. It would also probably be best to open `out` before you create the header, and use it rather than `os` throughout the program.

Comment: Wrap your streams (in and out) in `try-with-resource` and you wont have to worry about closing them. it will auto flush and close.

Comment: Thank you. I change from `"\n\r"` to `"\r\n"`. And now it is working.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by replacing `"\n\r"` to `"\r\n"`. Thank you.