# How to handle browser window dialog boxes using Selenium?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I have clicked on a hyperlink, which will generate a PDF report. I have to save it to my disc.
I can able to click on the link, but after that one window dialog box came with OK, Cancel buttons. How can I click on OK button in order to save the PDF file?

Comment: Can you paste the HTML content or some screenshot of that dialog?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to download a pdf file programmatticaly from a webpage with .html extension?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19309300/how-to-download-a-pdf-file-programmatticaly-from-a-webpage-with-html-extension)

Comment: I am trying to paste the image. But Stackoverflow site says that i should have 10 reputations :(