# EOFException with FileUtils.copyURLToFile

Tags: java, apache-commons, eofexception, apache-commons-io

I am trying to download the file to local disk from the URL. So I'm trying to use the

```
FileUtils.copyURLToFile(new URL(url), filename);
```

But I get `IOException` Occurred `java.io.EOFException`: End of input or Premature `EOF` often without complete download of file. Please let me know what's wrong in this line. What can I check before writing this file?

Comment: Have you tried [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19059244/how-to-use-fileutils-io-correctly) or with another URL and local file?

Answer (score 0):

The download was incomplete. There's nothing you can check beforehand, obviously. If this happens you should probably delete the target file.

Comment: I don't know why this answer was downvoted, but it seems like the right answer to me. It could perhaps be improved with a link to the documentation, which mentions that IOException will be thrown "if an IO error occurs during copying": http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#copyURLToFile(java.net.URL, java.io.File)

Comment: @DavidConrad Thanks. A link to EOFException might have been more appropriate, but the OP seems to know what it is. Re the downvote, maybe someone thinks it is possible to foretell an incomplete download? :-)

Comment: Can someone let me know how to resolve this issue? The link which iam using seems to be correct and its happening all the time at copyURLToFile line.

Comment: Can you download the file with a browser?